# How do I make a specific tag appear on click and hide the other one present in a div?

Tags: html, angular, sass

I'm trying to do a simple component that just change the icon img on click, it's two simple images. The problem is that the close icon doesn't even show up and the icon to open doesn't hide when I click on it.

I've tried adding `(click)="isVisible = !isVisible"` and `[ngClass]="{ 'isVisible': isVisible }"`

None of these seems to work, here is my HTML:

```
<div class="toggle" (click)="isVisible = !isVisible">
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/64/64576.png" class="icon-open" alt>
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/24/24139.png" class="icon-close"
        [ngClass]="{ 'isVisible': isVisible }" alt>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect `.icon-close` to show up and '.icon-open' to hide when I click on `.toggle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you should use angular's directive *ngIf.

```
<div class="toggle" (click)="isVisible = !isVisible">
    <div class="icon">
      <img *ngIf="isVisible" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/64/64576.png" class="icon-open" alt>
      <img *ngIf="!isVisible" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/24/24139.png" class="icon-close" alt>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a toggle class to toggle between 2 icons. I use something like below:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $(".closeButton").click(function () {
        $(".searchContents").slideToggle('1000');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fas fa-times fas fa-sort-down')
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this with Angular, I don't think I can't put jQuery in my current project

Answer (score 0):

As you are using hide and show functionality you need to create a two class for hide and show like.

```
.block {
  display: block;
}
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

and use it like

```
<div class="toggle" (click)="isVisible = !isVisible">
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/64/64576.png" height="30px" class="icon-open"  [ngClass]="{ 'isVisible': !isVisible }" alt>
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/24/24139.png" height="30px" class="icon-close"
    [ngClass]="{ 'block': isVisible,'none':!isVisible }" alt>
</div>
```

please check full demo here [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gx6fyh?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)